# Reason behind this paint peel

Tags: paint, wallpaper

Pictures are from the bathroom closet, only the paint in this closet is peeling. bathroom walls are fine.

Any idea why this paint is peeling by looking at pictures?

I was thinking to stick one of those wallpapers, do I have to repaint before sticking wall paper or I can scrap off old paint as much as I can and directly stick wallpaper to it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the material that the paint is on?  It's possible that the material was not prepped properly prior to painting.

Comment: Don't know, it looks and feels like a drywall, but paint is really getting peeled off of it, without leaving any residue.

Comment: looks like latex on oil

Comment: I have one of those ... the cabinet is made of some type of pressed paper material and it absorbs moisture, which makes it expand and then contract as it dries ... that motion causes the paint to peel